# Scala match: use value only available in subclass

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the code

```
abstract class Base

case class C1(val value1: Int) extends Base
case class C2(val value2: Int) extends Base

def match_test(thing: Base) = thing match {
  case _: C1 => println(C1.value1)
  case _: C2 => println(C2.value2)
}
```

But, the compiler produces errors (roughly):

```
value1 is not a member of object C1
value2 is not a member of object C2
```

I don't see why this error should be produced.  In each of the cases, it is matching a subclass, and that subclass has the required values.

How do you do this type of pattern matching correctly?

Comment: C1.value1 looks like a singleton object access rather than class object access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the val on an instance of the class, not the class itself:

```
def matchTest(thing: Base) = thing match {
  case x: C1 => println(x.value1)
  case y: C2 => println(y.value2)
}
```

You can also unpack the objects like this, since you are using case classes:

```
def matchTest(thing: Base) = thing match {
  case C1(v1) => println(v1)
  case C2(v2) => println(v2)
}
```